# Verify Equation Using Integral

Tags: calculus, partial-fractions

I have trouble understanding what needs to be done here using the following explanation. Without solving this problem, or by solving something similar, could someone explain what needs to be done here with the following info.

Confirm that:
$$\frac {1}{x^2 -1} = \frac {1}{2}(\frac {1}{x-1} - \frac {1}{x+1})$$

And use this equation to evaluate:
$$\int_2^6 \frac {3}{x^2 -1}\,dx$$

Comment: This assumes that you know $\int\frac1x=\log|x|+C$, right?

Comment: For the first part, you need to show that the two sides are always the same, regardless of $x$. Can you re-write the right hand side as a single fraction and try to simplify it? For the second part, notice that the thing you're integrating is very similar to the left hand side from the first part. Try re-writing the integrand using the equality from the first part and see if that's easier to integrate.

Comment: @yes. But it also assumes one cannot use hyperbolic trig functions.

Comment: Those will not be necessary.

Comment: @IzaakvanDongen can I just factor the 3 out in front of the integral? It would give me the left hand side of the equation

Comment: Yes, that's allowed. You can even leave the $3$ inside the integral and just multiply your equation from the first part by $3$ if you prefer that.

Comment: @IzaakvanDongen I'm still not sure how I would evaluate the integral without hyperbolic trig functions. And I have also confirmed the first equation to be true where x^2 cannot = 1.

Comment: It's good that you've noticed $x^2$ can't be $1$. This doesn't turn out to be a problem because in our integral, $2 \le x \le 6$. Now, once you've re-written the integral, the next step is to split it up into two integrals (where each integral is of one of the two fractions you're adding together) and make a substitution in each. Another commenter has already given you some idea of what the general form of the solution is going to be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you have confirmed that the first equation is valid, you can then use it:

\begin{align}
\int_2^6\frac3{x^2-1}\,dx&=3\int_2^6\frac1{x^2-1}\,dx\\
&=3\int_2^6\frac12\left(\frac1{x-1}-\frac1{x+1}\right)\,dx\\
&=\frac32\int_2^6\frac1{x-1}\,dx-\frac32\int_2^6\frac1{x+1}\,dx
\end{align}

As for how to evaluate these integrals, use the fact that $$\int_a^b\frac1x\,dx=\log|x|\bigg|_a^b.$$

To write it so the answer is in plain sight, we can let $u=x-1\implies du=dx$ and $v=x+1\implies dv=dx$ to produce the following:
$$\frac32\int_2^6\frac1{x-1}\,dx-\frac32\int_2^6\frac1{x+1}\,dx=\frac32\int_1^5\frac1u\,du-\frac32\int_3^7\frac1v\,dv$$
and you should be able to take it from here.

Answer (score 0):

Well lets start with the first equality:

$$\frac{1}{x^2-1}=\frac{1}{2}(\frac{1}{x-1}-\frac{1}{x+1})$$
Looking at the RHS:
$$\frac{1}{2}(\frac{1}{x-1}-\frac{1}{x+1})=\frac{1}{2}(\frac{x+1}{x^2-1}-\frac{x-1}{x^2+1})$$
$$=\frac{1}{2}\frac{2}{x^2+1}=\frac{1}{x^2-1}$$
So that formula holds. And it comes from partial fraction decomposition. We can rewrite the LHS as follows:
$$\frac{1}{(x-1)(x+1)}=\frac{A}{x-1}+\frac{B}{x+1}$$
$$1=A(x+1)+B(x-1)$$
Letting $x=-1$:
$$1=-2B\Rightarrow B=\frac{-1}{2}$$
Letting $x=1$:
$$1=2A\Rightarrow A=\frac{1}{2}$$
Thus we obtain:
$$\frac{1}{x^2-1}=\frac{1}{2}\frac{1}{x-1}-\frac{1}{2}\frac{1}{x+1}$$
So we can use this formula to now evaluate the integral:
$$\int_2^6\frac{3}{x^2-1}=3\int_2^6\frac{1}{x^2-1}$$
$$=\frac{3}{2}\int_2^6\frac{1}{x-1}-\frac{1}{x+1}$$
$$=\frac{3}{2}[\ln|x-1|-\ln|x+1|]|_2^6$$
$$=\frac{3}{2}[\ln|\frac{x-1}{x+1}|]|_2^6$$
$$=\frac{3}{2}(\ln(\frac{5}{7})-\ln(\frac{1}{3}))$$